# Loading an XIB having nil IBOutlets Properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, iboutlet

Please refer the following code.In which i have one property

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) CustomView *promptView;
```

and getter method is loading it using XIB.

```
- (CustomView *)promptView
    {
        if (!_promptView) {
            _promptView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomViewXIB" owner:self options:nil]  objectAtIndex:0];
            [_promptView.buttonCheckMark addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            _promptView.alertMessage.text = @"hello text";
            _promptView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        }

        return _promptView;
    }
```

But i am getting nil value for alertMessage

which is a IBOutlet and declared and connected to the CustomView.h as

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *alertMessage;
```

also tried to set the File Owner to **CustomView**. I am getting the UIView Object (promptView) perfectly but the properties are nil.
How to resolve this?

> Tried Following solutions

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Button event is working .I can set the button target and selector but alertMessage property is nil.

Comment: Have you changed the File Owner class of the View in the *CustomViewXIB* to **CustomView** ?

Comment: yeah i have tried that also

Comment: Please check my answer I think view class is not set .

Comment: Try clearing project and restarting xcode, It happened to me once, and problem was xcode itself.

Comment: @MohshinShah You are doing wrong.. Don't change the class of File Owner, change the class of View to **CustomView**.

Comment: @iphonic Tried that ..not working.

Comment: @meth Its is working now.Restarted and Cleared the xcode project. Thanks :) (y)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the screenshot 
[image]

did you do this ?

Comment: Please refer the images i have uploaded